# Can't pass ngModel through 2 levels

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, components

I am trying to pass ngModel through the second child component but as soon as I do that it doesn't work. 
To pass the ngModel I use this abstract class:

```
export abstract class AbstractValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
  _value: any = '';
  get value(): any { return this._value; };
  set value(v: any) {
    if (v !== this._value) {
      this._value = v;
      this.onChange(v);
    }
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    this._value = value;
    this.onChange(value);
  }

  onChange = (_) => { };
  onTouched = () => { };
  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }
}

export function MakeProvider(type: any) {
  return {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => type),
    multi: true,
  };
}
```

Then I have an input component that extends that abstract class:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss'],
  providers: [MakeProvider(InputComponent)],
})

export class InputComponent extends AbstractValueAccessor {
  @Input('displaytext') displaytext: string;
  @Input('placeholder') placeholder: string;
}
```

With this template:

```
<ion-input 
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  type="text"
  ></ion-input>
```

Works great like this:

```
<app-input [(ngModel)]="value"></app-input>
```

However, when I make a component around that like this one:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-input-item',
  templateUrl: './form-input-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-input-item.component.scss'],
  providers: [MakeProvider(FormInputItemComponent)],
})
export class FormInputItemComponent extends AbstractValueAccessor {
  @Input() position: string;
}
```

And use it this way:

```
<app-item>
  <app-label [position]="position"><ng-content></ng-content></app-label>
  <app-input [(ngModel)]="value"></app-input>
</app-item>
```

And then in its' parent I call it like:

```
<app-form-input-item *ngFor='let item of data' position="floating" [(ngModel)]="item.value">
  <b>{{item.title}}</b>
</app-form-input-item>
```

The ngModel is empty. I can edit it and it will change but something keeps emptying it. If I change `<app-input>` to `<ion-input>` it does work again. What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

This is what my app-item looks like:

```
<ion-item>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ion-item>
```

Stackblitz (with thanks to @GaurangDhorda): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uuoahx

Comment: can you share your problme here on stackblitz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find complete working example here in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ighh1c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

here, we are creating custom single `Atom` input component using `ControlValueAccessor`. **Input.component.html** is... as per [Atomic design pattern](http://atomicdesign.bradfrost.com/chapter-2/) whole answer is....

```
<input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="value">
```

Then, we are creating custom Class called `AbstractValueAccessor`, and implementing `ControlValueAccessor` in it. So that, whenever we need to convert any component to `ControlValueAccessor` we just extending `AbstractValueAccessor` class to class component.ts. so **input.component.ts** is...

```
export class InputComponent extends AbstractValueAccessor {
  ngOnInit() {
  } 
}
```

Custom **AbstractValueAccessor.ts** is...

```
import { Component, forwardRef, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
const noop = () => {
};
export abstract class AbstractValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {     
   //The internal data model
   private innerValue: any = '';

   //Placeholders for the callbacks which are later provided
   //by the Control Value Accessor
   private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
   private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;

   //get accessor
   get value(): any {
     return this.innerValue;
   };

   //set accessor including call the onchange callback
   set value(v: any) {
     if (v !== this.innerValue) {
         this.innerValue = v;
         this.onChangeCallback(v);
     }
   }

   //Set touched on blur
   onBlur() {
     this.onTouchedCallback();
   }

   //From ControlValueAccessor interface
   writeValue(value: any) {
      if (value !== this.innerValue) {
         this.innerValue = value;
      }
   }

   //From ControlValueAccessor interface
   registerOnChange(fn: any) {
       this.onChangeCallback = fn;
   }

   //From ControlValueAccessor interface
   registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
      this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
   }
}

export function MakeProvider(type: any) {
       return {
                provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
                useExisting: forwardRef(() => type),
                multi: true,
       };
}
```

Then in your **input.component.ts** you have to provide `MakeProvider()`

```
import {AbstractValueAccessor,MakeProvider} from '.././abstract-value-accessor';
 @Component({
    selector: 'app-input',
    templateUrl: './input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./input.component.css'] ,
    providers: [MakeProvider(InputComponent)],
 })
```

In **form-input-item** component use this custom input component. By Atomic Design Pattern this is called `Molecules`.

```
  <app-item>
    <app-input [(ngModel)]="value"></app-input>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </app-item>
```

this is your **main app.component.html**, This is called `Organisms` in Atomic Design.

```
<div style="box-shadow : 1px 2px 6px ; padding:1rem; margin: 0 auto; width:50vw" >
      <app-form-input-item [ngStyle]="{'margin': ' 0 auto' }" 
                    *ngFor="let galaxy of galaxies; let in=index;" [(ngModel)]="galaxy.name">
           <div style="box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #123456; margin:1em; padding:1em;    word-break: break-word;">
               {{galaxy.name}}
           </div>
           <hr style="border: .5px solid red">
       </app-form-input-item>

<app-form-input-item [(ngModel)]="bh" ></app-form-input-item>
```

You **app.component.ts** is..

```
 export class AppComponent  {
    name = 'Angular';
    galaxies = [
       {id:1,name:'Milky Way'},
       {id:2,name:'LMC'},
       {id:3,name:''},
       {id:4,name:'Cigar Galaxy'}
    ];
 }
```

Comment: Thank you but this isn't what I need. For the purpose of the Atomic design methodology I don't want to put `<app-input>` manually inside the `app.component.hmtl`. I want it to be in the component template. I only want to pass the `ngModel` within the `app.component.html`.

Comment: `i want it to be in component template` what does that mean?

Comment: In your example `component template` is the template wrapping the whole component. In Atom this would be a molecule. So I need the html to be  `<app-item><app-label></app-label><app-input></app-input></app-item>` and I want to call that with only `<app-form-input-item *ngFor='let item of data' position="floating" [(ngModel)]="item.value">
  <b>{{item.title}}</b>
</app-form-input-item>`. Atom Methodology: http://atomicdesign.bradfrost.com/chapter-2/

Comment: Then how you can put `<app-item>` into the `<app-form-input-item>`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to give that part of the code. I editted my question to contain `app-item`. Your question made me think of something. I think the reason it doesn't get ngModel is because `app-input` is within a `ng-content`.

Comment: Just to make my point clear I editted your stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6md19e

Comment: in stackblitz in `app.component.html` what is `{{item.title}}`?

Comment: check out this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-omv7s7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html stackblitz link

Comment: Yes but that is exactly my problem. Look this is how I want it to work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uuoahx Why are the values empty? Once it goes through the components they are being set as empty while they already have a value.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ighh1c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html this way you can get default value from model galaxy

Comment: simply, You can comment `// this.onChange(value);` in `AbstractValueAccessor` of `writeValue()`, so simply now your `writeValue(value:any){ this._value= value }` .

Comment: can you please upVote and accept answer if answer is helpful for you.

Comment: Sorry I've been too busy to test it lately. It works like a charm! If you can edit your answer to our last situation I will accept it.

Comment: Welcome, I have updated answer too.  you can  accept it. Thanks.